# php columns from xml

Tags: php, xml

How to make columns in `index.php`? Now just show everything in one column. I want 3 or 4 columns with 10 rows something like that.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents('https://somesite.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
$data = $xml->entry;
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
$title = $data[$i]->title;
$title = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('/-+/', '+', $title);
$item = $data[$i]->content;
$a = preg_match_all('#src="(.*?)"#',$item,$isi);
$img = $isi[1][0];
echo '<br><a href="download.php?q='.$title.'"><img src="'.$img.'"title='.$title.' /></br>';
```

Comment: This is more of an HTML/CSS question than PHP/XML. I think you should remove the `<br>`s and float the anchor elements though.

Comment: Im not very good in this, can you give me some example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, tested on local sample values might need some tweaking. Also your links weren't being closed, typo maybe?

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents('https://somesite.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
$data = $xml->entry;
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    $title = $data[$i]->title;
    $title = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/-+/', '+', $title);
    $item = $data[$i]->content;
    $a = preg_match_all('#src="(.*?)"#',$item,$isi);
    $img = $isi[1][0];
    echo '<a style="float:left; display:block;" href="download.php?q='.$title.'"><img src="'.$img.'"title='.$title.' /></a>';
    if($i % 4 == 0 && $i > 1) {
        echo '<div style="clear:both;" />';
    }   
}
if($i % 4 != 0) {
     //we didnt clear we should clear so other contents on the page arent floated
     echo '<div style="clear:both;" />';
}
?>
```

This is to display the links 4 per line, change the `$i % 4` to `$i % 3` if you want 3, and so on for others. That operator is called modulus, here's a doc on it http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic.

Comment: This messy my site from up to down :D

Comment: Are your images varying sizes?

Comment: No, its same size. 175x175

Comment: Hmm, can you post a screenshot or link of your site?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/54kvk6ru3/

Comment: Now it is in columns but when i put title code to show title after every image and become 1 column

Comment: What does the title code have, any `<br>`?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/vdxeh3txx/ this is with this code: 
echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';

When write <br> they are one under another.

Comment: to work with modulo can be a correct approach, but don't miss to clear floats *after* the loop as well.

Comment: The width of the title is throwing it off because it is all on the same line. How is the title being written, JS?